# Play iTunes Continously

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that plays a specific iTunes playlist.

```
tell application "iTunes"
  play user playlist myPlaylist
end tell
```

But this will only play the play list once, then it stops. What I want is for the playlist to reload, then play continuously 24/7 until someone actually stop or pause the iTunes.

I tried to modify the code to this, but it doesn't work.

```
on idle
  tell application "iTunes"
    play user playlist myPlaylist
  end tell
end idle
```

The on idle code actually does nothing, even after iTunes stops.

I also try to reload the user playlist, but also doesn't work.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat until player state is stopped
        play user playlist myPlaylist
    end repeat
end tell
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for repeating playlist does not work on iTunes 11.  The link regulusy6633 posted contains the answer.  The code below works for iTunes 11.

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"'s menu bar 1's menu bar item "Controls"'s menu 1's menu item "Repeat"'s menu 1
        perform action "AXPress" of menu item "All"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look in iTune's applescript dictionary at the "playlist" class you will see it has a command called "song repeat". Maybe that will help you.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    tell user playlist myPlaylist
        set song repeat to all
        play
    end tell
end tell
```

***EDIT***: As of itunes version 11 the above code no longer works. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674517/how-to-set-itunes-11-in-shuffle-or-repeat-mode-via-applescript/14679365#14679365) for solutions. I posted an answer there.

Comment: This has worked perfectly till a few days ago.  Now when I run the script, this is what I get. `test.scpt: execution error: iTunes got an error: Can't set song repeat of user playlist "myPlaylist" to all. (-10006)`

Comment: I added an EDIT section to my answer which can help with iTunes 11.

Comment: I refer to the link, and able to get it to work with this: `tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"'s menu bar 1's menu bar item "Controls"'s menu 1's menu item "Repeat"'s menu 1
    perform action "AXPress" of menu item "All"
end tell`