# How Do You Get Applescript Editor To Shuffle All iTunes Songs?

Tags: applescript, itunes

How Do You Get Applescript To Shuffle All iTunes Songs?
This Part I've Found out:

```
 tell application "iTunes"
       activate
       (...)
 end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Access to shuffle has been **removed** as of iTunes 11. I suggest you look at this post: [How to set iTunes 11 in shuffle or repeat mode via applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674517/how-to-set-itunes-11-in-shuffle-or-repeat-mode-via-applescript)

Answer (score 0):

For iTunes 12 and Music x:

--> SET MODE TO SONGS, ALBUMS OR GROUPINGS

tell application "iTunes" to set shuffle mode to songs