# In an Applescript file, how might I go about getting particular groups of albums to play at random

Tags: random, applescript, itunes

Say, only trying to get `Artists → All Artists` to play on random. Or playing `Genre → Metal` to play on random?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a list selecting Artist or Genre and then play random item I of that list :

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set MyList to every track whose genre is "pop"  
    set RandomNumber to random number from 1 to (count of MyList)
    play item RandomNumber of MyList
end tell
```

However, you need to add a repeat loop to keep playing a next random number.

If you have iTunes version lower than 11, you can still use the shuffle property of a play list. Since version 11, shuffle property is obsolete. But Regulus663 found a workaround in stack overflow 4 years ago; refer to that link : [How to set iTunes 11 in shuffle or repeat mode via applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674517/how-to-set-itunes-11-in-shuffle-or-repeat-mode-via-applescript)